# Libgdx gesture listener doesn't work in phone but works in desktop

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx, gesture

I have a game that I am building using libgdx. I have implemented some gesture functions using the `GestureListener` class. When I am testing this functions in the desktop, they work fine. But when I tested in a phone, they don't seem to respond. Am doing anything wrong here? Or do I have to make some changes for a phone.

Here is a link to my code: https://github.com/dhirajbodicherla/lyte/blob/master/core/src/com/mygdx/game/GameStage.java

Comment: Are those methods being entered at all when running on the phone?

Comment: No they are not entering. I tried to do a Gdx debug print and checked on the console. It didn't print even for `tap` method.

Comment: It looks like GestureListener implements InputProcessor so maybe you can get rid of 'implements InputProcessor' from your class and see what happens? Maybe something is getting confused there.

Comment: @jaykumarark either post your solution as answer or delete the question as it is completely useless as it is now.

Comment: @Barodapride I got it working. You were right. The input processor was getting in the way of the touch events meant for the gestures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GestureListener already implements InputProcessor so your class should only implement GestureListener otherwise the touch events don't get handled correctly.